# aligning heading and subheading in `pkgdown` article table of content (TOC)

Tags: html, css, r, pkgdown

I am building a `pkgdown` website for my R package. Everything is working well, but one customization I haven't managed to figure out is how to align article headings and subheadings in a table of content (**TOC**).

In the image below,

- On the left: article from my `ggstatsplot` package website 
  (https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/ggstatsplot/articles/web_only/effsize_interpretation.html)
- On the right: article from `broom` package website 
  (https://broom.tidyverse.org/articles/adding-tidiers.html)

Note that the **headings** (red arrows) in the TOC in `ggstatsplot` article are all vertically aligned with the **subheadings**, while the TOC for `broom` article distinguishes between a heading and a subheading in terms of lateral separation. This is what I want but can't seem to figure out how to do.

[image]

**In short**: how can I turn the left TOC to look like the one on the right in terms of creating lateral separation between a given heading and subheadings below it?

Here is `_pkgdown.yml` for my package: 
https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot/blob/master/_pkgdown.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following CSS rule should fix the indentation issue. You can add this to [pkgdown/extra.css](https://pkgdown.r-lib.org/reference/init_site.html?q=extracss#arguments).

```
#tocnav ul ul {
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

The CSS adds a left margin of 25px to any nested list under `#tocnav`. Adjust the margin size as needed. Targeting only the `#tocnav` is a conservative approach, but there may be other places in your pkgdown site that need this rule as well.